# Why doesn't the following jquery script work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple single page setup.  Under a root folder, I have 3 subfolders (js, css, and images).  In the root folder, I have an index.html page with the following content:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a onclick="doSomething()" href="#" class="doSomething">Click!</a>
</body>
<html>
```

myscript.js contains the following code:

```
$('a.doSomething').click(function(){
//Do Something here!
alert('You did sometihng, woo hoo!');
});
```

When I click the link, nothing happens.  What am I missing?

Comment: Tip: Don't do href="#", it isn't necessary (and often annoying). If you want the hand-pointer to show up use CSS for that.

Comment: Just going through a tutorial now and typing it verbatim lol.

Comment: No worries, just a tip for future reference.

Comment: Open to any helpful tips,  Thanks d03boy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap document.ready around the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.doSomething').click(function(){
        //Do Something here!
        alert('You did sometihng, woo hoo!');
        return false; // return false to prevent default action
    });
});
```

As it is right now, you are trying to bind an event to an element that does not yet exist in the DOM.

Also, not sure why you have the `onclick` on the link itself, as the whole point of jQuery is to be able to take those ugly inline events out of there and bind them cleanly in the javascript. If you do this:

```
<a href="#" class="doSomething">yay click me</a>
```

And then use the code above, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I am following a tutorial on how to use jquery properly.  It talks about using unobtrusive javascript.  I am not sure how to do it with the onclick though.  Here is the link if you are interested:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/16/jquery-examples-and-best-practices/

Comment: lol, you answered my question before I posted it.  Thanks agin.

Comment: Just realized I mispelled your name.  Sorry about that Paolo.

Comment: No problem. :) Good luck with it, jQuery is awesome once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought you were just missing a function named "doSomething".  Then I realized you where expecting your selector to find the anchor tag anyway.  However, that won't happen.  At the time your script runs, the anchor hasn't been added to the DOM yet.